# Time-out for two-table mysql update statement - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fill in some missing data in one table from a second table using the following statement (XX and YY are set to integer values.

```
update ignore sub, user set sub.username=user.username
where sub.id>=XX and sub.id<YY and user.id=sub.user_id
and sub.status>0 and sub.username is null
```

sub is indexed on id
user is indexed on id

This goes fine for a part of the sub table where there are corresponding user values, but starts timing out when user values cannot be found. Why is mysql having trouble with this? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you append an exact error message ? Is that `lock wait timeout` or some other timeout ? How long does the query take ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing an index on user_id field in sub table.

Add index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `sub`
ADD INDEX (`user_id`);
```

If the query is still slow run this and post the results:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM
    `sub`,
    `user`
WHERE
    `sub`.`id` >= XX
    AND `sub`.`id` < YY
    AND `user`.`id` = `sub`.`user_id`
    AND `sub`.`status` > 0
    AND `sub`.`username` IS NULL
;
```